# Sort, copy value from table to another table and calculate new value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to create spreadsheet to calculate my current bank balance. I want to write down all history of payment. Here's the example

[image]

So I need formula to create from table "buy - sell" tale "balance"

Is it even posible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `=SUMIF()` formula to get the total buy price and sell price for a particular date and then add the resulting subtraction from the balance from day before. See the image attached

[image]

Formula: `=I4+(SUMIF($D$2:$D$3,H5,$E$2:$E$3) - SUMIF($A$2:$A$3, H5, B4:B5))`

`I4`: the balance from the previous day
`SUMIF($D$2:$D$3,H5,$E$2:$E$3)`: Sum of the sell price (range E2:E3) for a particular date (in this case H5, checking in the range D2:D3)
`SUMIF($A$2:$A$3, H5, B4:B5)`: Sum of the buy price (range B2:B3) for a particular date (in this case H5, checking in the range A2:A3)

Simply drag the formula to all the dates below. The formula will also take of multiple entries on the same date

Comment: What do you want then? It is as per your description

Comment: I have to on my own create dates. In real scenario I'll have few days gaps, so I need something to read dates from left table and based on that data, create right table.

Comment: The formula will still work even if there are gaps in the dates on the right. If you want to get a unique list of dates used on the left table, you will have to either do it manually using Excel's Remove Duplicates feature or use VBA